# Why I can't push items into this array?

Tags: solidity, truffle, cpp-ethereum

it's very tricky，
when in the truffle , I call f()，it can't push an item into addressArray.(console.log(addressArray[0]) always unidifined))
but when I use Remix, it worked.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

    contract Test{
        address[] public addressArray;
    
        function f() public {
            addressArray.push(msg.sender);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling `f()`? How are you accessing `addressArray`? It should be possible. To access `addressArray` from the truffle's console you should do something like `console.log(await testContract.addressArray(0))`, since it is a getter function.

Comment: thank you, It worked when I use testContract.addressArray(0) instead of testContract.addressArray[0];   :0

Comment: but another question is how can I get this length of the array?  when I use `console.log(await testContract.addressArray.length)`   it's undifined

Comment: If you have a new question you should search the site is someone has already asked or create a new one. To get the length you have to add a getter function to the contract.